# How do I get a different random result each time in a while loop?

Tags: python

```
import random
randatk=random.randint(1,10)  
randheal=random.randint(1,10)
mnstrhp=100
playerhp=100
while mnstrhp>0:
    atkorheal=input("would you like to attack the monster or heal yourself? ")
    if 'attack' in atkorheal:
        print("you did" , randatk , "damage to the monster!")
        print("the monster's current health is " , mnstrhp-randatk)
    if 'heal' in atkorheal:
        print("you healed for" , randheal  , "health!")
        print("your current hp is " , playerhp+randheal)
```

i am aiming to get a different random result each time the program loops, but instead, every time the program loops, it is always the same number. Is there any way to get a different value every time?

Comment: Put the `random` inside the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The randint() call should be in your loop. You are currently only generating one random number and using it n times.